# exporting Data in the DB to excelsheet using XSLT technology

Tags: php, xml, excel, xslt

I have server side script as PHP . I have some set of records in the DB which i have to programmatically export it to excel sheet  using XSLT technology .  Can you provide some examples  using XSLT and PHP. I searched in php manual but could not find it

Comment: You couldn't find the [XSL](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) section of the manual?

Comment: @Charles: Any Simple Example for Exporting to Data using XSL

Comment: I think that XSL is an abomination and should be nuked from orbit, just to be sure.  The chances of me giving you an example of how to use it is kind of unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explicitly stated to what kind of Excel you want to export your data.

If it's just tabular data without any adornments, then the simplest is to export your data to CSV. You don't need any XML or XSLT to do that. All you need is a CSV generating facility.

If, on the other hand, you want to export data to some spiced up Excel sheet in the new XML format, then export your data from the database as XML and code up a suitable XSL transformation to create your desired Excel/XML output.